# I'm getting confused with objects and classes

Tags: python

I am trying to make a text based adventure game, i am getting heavily confused with passing around objects and classes to be able to move from room to room etc. I have made a mess of my code, i am only starting to learn python.

I've tried just a dictionary of variables, classes on there own and i kept getting errors for not being able to call their attributes

The problem is that i want to be able to change the location of adventurer to the 'west' of the starting room and then be able to use that location to check in the world dictionary when moving back and forth the rooms.

```py
destination = world[character.location].east 
character.location = destination
```

This does not work ^

it doesn't change character.location

```py
import os
import time
import sys

class Adventurer:
    def __init__(self, starting):
        self.name = ''
        self.inv = []
        self.location = starting
        self.game_over = False

class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, info, location):
        self.name = name
        self.info = info
        self.location = world[location]

class Room:
    def __init__(self, name, description, north, south, east, west, roominv):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.north = north
        self.south = south
        self.east = east
        self.west = west
        self.roominv = roominv

def prompt():
    print("\n" + "=============================")
    print("Please enter a command")
    command = input("> ")
    available_commands = ['east', 'west', 'look']
    while command.lower() not in available_commands:
        print("Unknown command, if you need help with commands try 'help'" + "\n")
        command = input("> ")
    if(command.lower() == 'quit'):
        sys.exit()
    elif(command.lower() in ['west', 'go west', 'w']):
        if move_check(world[character.location].west):
            destination = world[character.location].west
            movement_handler(destination)
    elif(command.lower() in ['east', 'go east', 'e']):
        if move_check(world[character.location].east):
            destination = world[character.location].east
            movement_handler(destination)
    elif(command.lower() == 'look'):
        print(world[character.location].name)

def move_check(direction):
    if direction == 'NA':
        print("You cannot go this direction.\n")
        return False
    else:
        return True

def movement_handler(destination):
    print("You head to the " + destination + ".")
    character.location = destination

def main_game_loop():
    while character.game_over is False:
        prompt()

def start_game():
    os.system('cls')
    question1 = ("What would you like to name your character?\n")
    message_write(question1)

    character_name = input("> ")
    character.name = character_name

    welcome = "Welcome " + character_name + "\n"
    message_write(welcome)
    speech1 = "You awake in a dark room with no memory of how you got there.\n"
    speech2 = "You must find a way out or be stuck forever.\n"
    message_write(speech1)
    message_write(speech2)

    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls')
    print("#############")
    print("#   START   #")
    print("#############")
    print('\n')

    main_game_loop()

def message_write(message):
    for char in message:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.01)

starting = ''
candle = ''

world = {
    starting: Room("Starting Room", "You are in a dark room with nothing around", "NA", "NA", "NA", 'candle', []),
    candle: Room("Candle Room", "It is cold but there are unlit candles in the corner of the room", "NA", "NA", 'starting', "NA", [])
    }



character = Adventurer(starting)

start_game()
```

Comment: please add full stack of your error

Comment: This site is for asking specific questions, so you should describe a particular problem (and show the error message).

Comment: This is far too broad. If you need help with a specific error, post the error and describe what you already attempted to solve it.

Comment: you might consider putting  this question on the code review site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what just happened to the formatting?  The original question had code that essentially ran . This doesn't look right to me

Comment: Someone told me to sort out the formatting or something and to not post the full code?

Comment: There is no implementation of `start_game` and the question is not properly formulated please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've run your previous snippet of code, it's hard to track you logic through the code, but the main issue seems to be with your checks in the `prompt` function: `if move_check(world[character.location].west) :KeyError: 'starting'`. The construct is rather strange, you have the `world` dict which is actually the attribute of `Item` object. I would recommend to start it from the begging and use the following building system: https://github.com/evennia/evennia/wiki/Evennia-Introduction

Comment: notwithstanding discussion about question breadth, I'm going to recommend you edit it to include the complete, executable code which I found ran (and exhibited strange behavior as you said).  regardless of whether the question remains open, including only snippets of the code does no good.  Instead, include the complete code, which I wouldn't call excessively long, and the error message you're getting.  I'm working on what i think will be a helpful answer.

Comment: Theres the full code, i know the error is with the 'world[character.location].west' bit but i'm asking for alternative ways because that doesnt work

Comment: Discord is Thyrox#6187 if its easier to talk on there

Comment: Your description of the problem only states what you _want_ to — what is preventing you from doing it (or what is not working when you try to do that)?

Answer (score 1):

First, an overt error.  This is probably what you're hitting when you

```
> look
Traceback (most recent call last):
[ ... traceback omitted ... ]
    print(world[character.location].name)
KeyError: 'starting'
```

Which is happening here:

```
starting = ''
candle = ''

world = {
    starting: Room("Starting Room", "You are in a dark room with nothing around", "NA", "NA", "NA", 'candle', []),
    candle: Room("Candle Room", "It is cold but there are unlit candles in the corner of the room", "NA", "NA", 'starting', "NA", [])
    }
```

Here you're thinking `world` will be a `dict` in which each value is a room ,and that value's key is the room's identifier.  That makes sense ... but whereas you want the identifier to be a string `"starting"`, instead you set a *variable* `starting` whose value is empty string.

`dict` objects have *one* key per *one* value, so since `starting` and `candle` variables are both the same value, empty string, you can't actually store them both under the same key (ie `''`).

The error happens when you try to refer to the room `world["candle"]` or `world["starting"]`, because neither has been defined .  Only `world[""]` has been defined - twice - but that's not going to do you any good; you already know you need *unique* names for each room for this to work.

You want is the literal identifier to be the value:

```
world = {
    "starting": Room("Starting Room", "You are in a dark room with nothing around", "NA", "NA", "NA", 'candle', []),
    "candle": Room("Candle Room", "It is cold but there are unlit candles in the corner of the room", "NA", "NA", 'starting', "NA", [])
    }
```

Then again below,

```
character = Adventurer(starting)
```

is going to evaluate to `Adventurer("")`.  You want

```
character = Adventurer("starting").
```

It's fine to leave the string in a variable if you like; but then you have to set variable `starting` to string `"starting"`:

```
starting = "starting"
...
character = Adventurer(starting)
```

Let's get into the more interesting meat of your question.

> i am getting heavily confused with passing around objects and classes to be 
>    able to move from room to room etc. I have made a mess of my code

You're already using classes to create what might be called "ownership" of variables.  a "Room" consists of its `name`, `description`, `north`, `south`, `east`, `west`, and `roominv`).  You might also say it "encapsulates" or "wraps"  all that data or even that it "owns" the data.

Ownership is the perspective I want to explore because I want to ask the question: who owns the *logic* of the code in the functions that are defined *outside* the classes?  The class definitions are just variable assignment; all the imperative parts of the code are defined in functions `prompt`, `start_game`, etc *outside* of the classes you used to structure your code.  Thus, you feel like your code is "messy"; it is!  Though the data is organized decently well, your logic isn't really organized much at all.

So the question is, which class should "own" what of the logic?  This is the fun and tricky bit of object oriented programming - organizing the code and the data of your program into classes that elegantly express the logical organization of your algorithm.  If you get the ownership right, you won't have to pass around very much state; you'll be able to leverage the ownership of the class whose methods you invoke to implicitly provide the context of your code's operations.

Your classes currently make pretty good sense:

- `Room` knows what's in it, and "links" to other rooms by optionally storing the ID to each room under "east", "west", etc.
- `Item` knows its name, info, and location;
- `Adventurer` knows its name, location, inventory, and game over flag

But we're ready to make some observations, too:

- who owns an items location, the `Item` or the `Room`?  Obviously `Room` owns its items as `Item` wouldn't have a list of other items in the room.  Perhaps `Item` doesn't need to refer to its location at all.  Perhaps if it were to interact with a location, it would own the *logic* of how to interact with a location ,and would instead be passed one when the interaction occurs?  Now we are thinking about who *owns* the logic in addition to the variables.
- What ties `Room`, `Item`, and `Adventurer` together?  Do you benefit from an object to represent your `Game` or `World`?

I'm not suggesting that you necessarily attempt to put *every* function in a class - `write_message` doesn't fit clearly into your paradigm and you gain little in trying to shove it in somewhere.

`prompt`, however, has to be reorganized.  Its name implies that it collects the intended action from the user - but it actually also process that action and applies it to the world.  If you look at this block of code:

```
    available_commands = ['east', 'west', 'look']
    while command.lower() not in available_commands:
        print("Unknown command, if you need help with commands try 'help'" + "\n")
        command = input("> ")
    if(command.lower() == 'quit'):
        sys.exit()
    elif(command.lower() in ['west', 'go west', 'w']):
        if move_check(world[character.location].west):
            destination = world[character.location].west
            movement_handler(destination)
    elif(command.lower() in ['east', 'go east', 'e']):
        if move_check(world[character.location].east):
            destination = world[character.location].east
            movement_handler(destination)
    elif(command.lower() == 'look'):
        print(world[character.location].name)
```

All the logic is essentially focused on deciding which *class attribute* direction to use for the given *user input* string.  In other words, you're going out of your way to use a class attribute for `east` , `west`, etc, even though in your model the name is actually pretty arbitrary and the input comes in as a text string.  Why not just use a string identifier for the direction like you did for the room id?  Each room could have a `dict` of direction ( now it doesn't have to be cardinal, could also be "ladder up", "chute down", etc) and the next `room`.

The general pattern I'm suggesting is "map relationships in the data, not the code".  You'll want to consider this any time you find yourself iterating over options and wanting to apply the same code to each.

Let's get into specifics.

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, name, description, directions, roominv):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.directions = directions
        self.roominv = roominv
    def move_check(self, direction):
      if direction in self.directions.keys():
        return True
      print("You cannot go this direction.\n")
      return False
```

```
def prompt():
    print("\n" + "=============================")
    print("Please enter a command")
    # prompt knows about these commands
    available_commands = ['quit','look']
    # current room knows about these commands
    available_commands.extend(world[character.location].directions.keys())
    command = input("> ").lower()
    if command not in available_commands:
      print(f"Unknown command, try one of {available_commands}", "\n", "if you need help with commands try 'help'", "\n")
      return
    if command.lower() == 'quit':
        sys.exit()
    elif command == "look":
        print(world[character.location].name)
    elif command in world[character.location].directions.keys():
      if world[character.location].move_check(command):
            destination = world[character.location].directions[command]
            movement_handler(destination)
```

```
world = {
    "starting": Room("Starting Room", "You are in a dark room with nothing around", { "west": "candle" }, []),
    "candle": Room("Candle Room", "It is cold but there are unlit candles in the corner of the room", { "east": "starting" }, [])
    }
```

I just took out the hard coded attribues `Room.east` etc and replaced with a dict of direction name to room.  Now instead of hard coding a whole bunch of relationships between string inputs and class attributes, I just use the string as the key to `Room.directions`.  I add the current room's `direction.keys()` to the list of available commands.

`main_game_loop()` already loops, so there's no need to confuse `prompt()` with the logic of looping until a valid command is entered.  And I no longer have to loop over hard coded directions to match to attributes.

I call `lower()` only once, which further simplifies things.  It's easy to see the logic behind your call of `lower()`, but its presence in every other line still obscures the more important logic behind the code flow.

This version takes the same set of inputs as your original code, but only because you hadn't added your "go west" / "w" aliases to `available_commands`.  Deciding how to alias in a more general case like this is something that should help inform your code organization.  ( Who owns the alias?  The room?  The direction?  A heuristic like "`go "direction"` always matches "direction"?  Is a `Room.directions` dict even how to do this best?).

I'm modeling the data in a way that allows me to do a generic action instead of a hard coded action.  This allows me to start thinking about the code in terms of the necessary input and output to make a decision like "which room are we going to?"  That helps me decide how to organize my code for extensibility.

I start defining a little bit of code ownership.  It isn't hard to believe that `move_check` would "belong" to `Room`.  Perhaps as the code adds features you'll find that `Room` isn't itself able to determine whether a move can be made, but it will certainly be part of the equation.  In the meantime,  we've organized the code just a little better.

But you can go farther.  What about the `look` and `quit` commands? themselves?  Who owns the relationship between `"look"` and getting a `Room.description`?  It depends on what might affect the flow.  For example, if the `Adventurer` has an `Item` that provides illumination, then maybe `look` is a reference to something `Adventurer` does and `Illumination` is something an `Item` might be able to do that `Adventurer` would check for.  `quit` is something `Game` might know how to do.

You could `available_commands.extend(source)` for all `source`s of commands relevant for a particular place, including eg `Adventurer`'s `use` command or other actions, a room's `directions.keys()`, etc.

Having to implement each such relationship in `prompt` is unwieldy and inextensible.  But if you model those relationships differently, a more elegant and extensible game engine loop emerges.  Pretty soon `prompt` doesn't have to change to implement new features, which are simple to express in the context of `Adventurer` ,`Item`, and `Room`.

But before you get much farther, you'll have to reconsider the mechanism of user input.  `use` is a one-word command, but how to use items will depend on what you want to use it *on*.  `go` works the same way, if you're willing to force the command "west" to become "go west".  suddenly we have a generic pattern " ".  We could pass the rest of "" to the "go" action handler for `Adventurer` so that Adventurer owns the logic of how to `go` somewhere,.  `Adventurer` could generally provide a current  list of what can be done, `go`, `use`, `look`, etc, and can own how that action is done in context of active items, location, etc.

You can further delegate parts of that process to individual components.  If a candle Item illuminates, a torch might do so better, and a headlamp best of all.  You'll want the `Item` to own the process of deciding, lest the `Adventurer` have to know all about each type of Illumination just like `prompt` had to know about each potential direction.   I'm guessing describing this flow of ownership will be your next big game implementation challenge.  Describing how the [chanin of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) design pattern is  too much for even this post , but it's what I'd probably use to handle "layering" the delgation of all the different relevant components to a general game action.

This should reveal new ways to organize your logic alongside your data to better organize your code.

Finally, I'm going to slip this in even though it reeks of opinionation:

```
sh: cls: command not found
```

On my Mac, as it would on Linux or any OS other than windows, your program spits that out instead of clearing the screen.  You might ask yourself, is clearing the screen really all that important to you?  I for one like the ability to scroll through my console history.  In a text based game like this, it would be perhaps advantageous to *not* clear the screen.  Anyway, I get that error message and no clear screen now.

I want to include my new code for the program, and example output, below:

```
$ python3 t.py
sh: cls: command not found
What would you like to name your character?
> Daniel
Welcome Daniel
You awake in a dark room with no memory of how you got there.
You must find a way out or be stuck forever.
sh: cls: command not found
#############
#   START   #
#############



=============================
Please enter a command
> east
Unknown command, try one of ['quit', 'look', 'west']
 if you need help with commands try 'help'


=============================
Please enter a command
> west
You head to the candle.

=============================
Please enter a command
> look
Candle Room

=============================
Please enter a command
> west
Unknown command, try one of ['quit', 'look', 'east']
 if you need help with commands try 'help'


=============================
Please enter a command
> east
You head to the starting.

=============================
Please enter a command
> look
Starting Room

=============================
Please enter a command

> quit
```

```
import os
import time
import sys

class Adventurer:
    def __init__(self, starting):
        self.name = ''
        self.inv = []
        self.location = starting
        self.game_over = False

class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, info, location):
        self.name = name
        self.info = info
        self.location = world[location]

class Room:
    def __init__(self, name, description, directions, roominv):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.directions = directions
        self.roominv = roominv
    def move_check(self, direction):
      if direction in self.directions.keys():
        return True
      print("You cannot go this direction.\n")
      return False

def prompt():
    print("\n" + "=============================")
    print("Please enter a command")
    # prompt knows about these commands
    available_commands = ['quit','look']
    # current room knows about these commands
    available_commands.extend(world[character.location].directions.keys())
    command = input("> ").lower()
    if command not in available_commands:
      print(f"Unknown command, try one of {available_commands}", "\n", "if you need help with commands try 'help'", "\n")
      return
    if command.lower() == 'quit':
        sys.exit()
    elif command == "look": 
        print(world[character.location].name)
    elif command in world[character.location].directions.keys():
      if world[character.location].move_check(command):
            destination = world[character.location].directions[command]
            movement_handler(destination)

def movement_handler(destination):
    print("You head to the " + destination + ".")
    character.location = destination

def main_game_loop():
    while character.game_over is False:
        prompt()

def start_game():
    os.system('cls')
    question1 = ("What would you like to name your character?\n")
    message_write(question1)

    character_name = input("> ")
    character.name = character_name

    welcome = "Welcome " + character_name + "\n"
    message_write(welcome)
    speech1 = "You awake in a dark room with no memory of how you got there.\n"
    speech2 = "You must find a way out or be stuck forever.\n"
    message_write(speech1)
    message_write(speech2)

    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls')
    print("#############")
    print("#   START   #")
    print("#############")
    print('\n')

    main_game_loop()

def message_write(message):
    for char in message:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.01)


world = {
    "starting": Room("Starting Room", "You are in a dark room with nothing around", { "west": "candle" }, []),
    "candle": Room("Candle Room", "It is cold but there are unlit candles in the corner of the room", { "east": "starting" }, []) 
    }

character = Adventurer("starting")

start_game()
```

Comment: Honestly thank you so much, this helped me understand everything so much clearer. Thank you for your help and time to answer this, was a very long answer and i appreciate it :D

Comment: 1 more quick questions,                                                                        
 `print("\nObvious Exits: ", world[character.location].directions.keys())`,   How can you print this without it printing as "dict_keys(['east'])"

Comment: try `print("\nObvious Exits: ", ", ".join(world[character.location].directions.keys()))` to create a list of the keys with `, ` between each